# how to use jq to filter select items not in list?

Tags: arrays, json, select, jq, blacklist

In jq, I can select an item *in* a list fairly easily:

```
$ echo '["a","b","c","d","e"]' | jq '.[] | select(. == ("a","c"))'
```

Or if you prefer to get it as an array:

```
$ echo '["a","b","c","d","e"]' | jq 'map(select(. == ("a","c")))'
```

But how do I select all of the items that are *not* in the list? Certainly `. != ("a","c")` does not work:

```
$ echo '["a","b","c","d","e"]' | jq 'map(select(. != ("a","c")))'
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d",
  "d",
  "e",
  "e"
]
```

The above gives every item twice, except for `"a"` and `"c`"

Same for:

```
$ echo '["a","b","c","d","e"]' | jq '.[] | select(. != ("a","c"))'
"a"
"b"
"b"
"c"
"d"
"d"
"e"
"e"
```

How do I filter *out* the matching items?

Comment: That was brutally painful, but I did manage to get it.

Comment: Your filter is effectively the same as `. != "a" or . != "c"`. That of course would always be true so you're not seeing anything filtered. However you're getting duplicates now since you're using the comma operator. Remember, for every value produced from commas, the expression is reevaluated with the new values. So `select(. != ("a","c"))` becomes `select(. != "a"), select(. != "c")`. Then it should be very clear what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @JeffMercado. I could not figure out why it didn't work. Essentially `. != ("a","c")` is logic OR, where I was expecting logical AND (even though `. == ("a","c")` is logical OR).

Comment: Not really. It's more like `("a","c")` is two values `"a"` and `"c"`. For any expression that uses it, copy the expression substituting the values `"a"` and `"c"` for the copies.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest and most robust (w.r.t. jq versions) approach would be to use the builtin `-`:

```
$ echo '["a","b","c","d","e"]' | jq -c '. - ["a","c"]'
["b","d","e"]
```

If the blacklist is very long and riddled with duplicates, then it might be appropriate to remove them (e.g. with `unique`).

#### Variations

The problem can also be solved (in jq 1.4 and up) using `index` and `not`, e.g.

```
["a","c"] as $blacklist
| .[] | select( . as $in | $blacklist | index($in) | not)
```

Or, with a variable passed in from the command-line (jq --argjson blacklist ...):

```
.[] | select( . as $in | $blacklist | index($in) | not)
```

To preserve the list structure, one can use `map( select( ...) )`.

With jq 1.5 or later, you could also use `any` or `all`, e.g.

```
def except(blacklist):
  map( select( . as $in | blacklist | all(. != $in) ) );
```

#### Special case: strings

See e.g. [Select entries based on multiple values in jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704404/select-entries-based-on-multiple-values-in-jq)

Comment: how do you use `any` here? Can you share an example?

Comment: FYI, what I did was: `def inarray($val;ary): ary | any(. == $val); def notinarray($val;ary): ary | all(. != $val); `

Comment: Aha! The `-` operator! Thank you @peak. So `-` is equivalent to "not in "a" AND not in "c"" ?

Comment: For the `-` variant (by far the simplest), what do you do if the input is an array, e.g `[{"val":"a"},{"val":"b"},{"val":"c"},{"val":"d"},{"val":"e"}]` and you want to filter by `.val - ["a","c"]` (which doesn't work)?

Comment: @deitch - I would suggest you create a new SO question.

Comment: With jq 1.6 or later, `IN` can be used: `echo '["a","b","c","d","e"]' | jq '.[] | select(. | IN("a", "c") | not)'`

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure it is not the most simple solution, but it works :)

```
$ echo '["a","b","c","d","e"]' | jq '.[] | select(test("[^ac]"))'
```

**Edit:** one more solution - this is even worse :)

```
$ echo '["a","b","c","d","e"]' | jq '.[] | select(. != ("a") and . != ("b"))'
```

Comment: Using the regex is nice idea, but this actually is just a simple sample. I am comparing against an array of items. I wish it *were* just single chars.

Comment: @deitch: You can still use `test`, just invert the result with `not`, e.g.: `test("^(abc|bcd)$") | not`

Comment: @Thor that is interesting. Could I do it with a variable, e.g. `js --arg match "abc" '.[] | select(test("^($match)$") | not` ?

Comment: @Picard, I originally did it with your alternate solution. The problem is that I have an unknown in advance list of items to match against.

Comment: From what I understand, your initial solution doesn't work because it checks each letter from the input array with each item from the matching list - so it matches the input "a" with the "a" from the list (no != match) then "a" with "c" (yes != match) so it outputs the input "a" (although you'd thought that is shouldn't). If it would be a "set-of-elements" element type  maybe the things would be different but from how the lists work I don't think there's a short, one operator solution to this.

Comment: @deitch: Yes ` jq --arg match 'bcd' '.[] | select(test("^("+$match+")$") | not)'`

Comment: In any case, I do have a solution, but cannot post it for 2 days. Oh well.