# Select entries based on multiple values in jq

Tags: json, jq, whitelist

I'm working with JQ and I absolutely love it so far. I'm running into an issue I've yet to find a solution to anywhere else, though, and wanted to see if the community had a way to do this.

Let's presume we have a JSON file that looks like so:

```
{"author": "Gary", "text": "Blah"}
{"author": "Larry", "text": "More Blah"}
{"author": "Jerry", "text": "Yet more Blah"}
{"author": "Barry", "text": "Even more Blah"}
{"author": "Teri", "text": "Text on text on text"}
{"author": "Bob", "text": "Another thing to say"}
```

Now, we want to select rows where the value of `author` is equal to either "Gary" OR "Larry", but no other case. In reality, I have several thousand names I'm checking against, so simply stating the direct or conditional (e.g. `cat blah.json | jq -r 'select(.author == "Gary" or .author == "Larry")'`) isn't sufficient. I'm trying to do this via the `inside` function like so but get an error dialog:

```
cat blah.json | jq -r 'select(.author | inside(["Gary", "Larry"]))'
```

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): array (["Gary","La...) and string ("Gary") cannot have their containment checked
```

What would be the best method for doing something like this?

Comment: You don't need `inside` function, you could get entries like `select(.author == ("Gary", "Larry"))`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`inside` and `contains` are a bit weird.  Here are some more straightforward solutions:

#### index/1

```
select( .author as $a | ["Gary", "Larry"] | index($a) )
```

#### any/2

```
["Gary", "Larry"] as $whitelist
| select( .author as $a | any( $whitelist[]; . == $a) )
```

#### Using a dictionary

If performance is an issue and if "author" is always a string, then a solution along the lines suggested by @JeffMercado should be considered. Here is a variant (to be used with the -n command-line option):

```
["Gary", "Larry"] as $whitelist
| ($whitelist | map( {(.): true} ) | add) as $dictionary
| inputs
| select($dictionary[.author])
```

Answer (score 18):

IRC user gnomon answered this on the [jq channel](http://irc.lc/freenode/%23jq/) as follows:

`jq 'select([.author] | inside(["Larry", "Garry", "Jerry"]))'`

The intuition behind this approach, as stated by the user was: "Literally your idea, only wrapping `.author` as `[.author]` to coerce it into being a single-item array so `inside()` will work on it." This answer produces the desired result of filtering for a series of names provided in a list as the original question desired.

Comment: This will perform a substring search. `"Lar"` and `"erry"` and `"J"` will all match.

Answer (score 5):

You can use objects as if they're sets to test for membership. Methods operating on arrays will be inefficient, especially if the array may be huge.

You can build up a set of values prior to reading your input, then use the set to filter your inputs.

```
$ jq -n --argjson names '["Larry","Garry","Jerry"]' '
(reduce $names[] as $name ({}; .[$name] = true)) as $set
    | inputs | select($set[.author])
' blah.json
```