# How to loop through a json array and find a match for each item in bigger json fille?

Tags: json, jq, whitelist

For example, I have this json file:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Bob",
    "Grade": "Pass"
  },
  { 
    "Name": "Alice",
    "Grade": "Fail"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Mallory",
    "Grade": "Fail"
  }
]
```

And this array `["Bo", "Al"]`

How do I loop through the array to check the json file for those students only and output their {Name, Grade}?

Also a note, I can do a series of pipes of `select(test(.Name == "Bob"))` but I can't hardcode it as the array is being generated dynamically depending on a selection.

Let me know if you need further clearance.

Thank you!

Note: Edited to ask how to do this for substrings, like "Bo" and "Al" for "Bob" and "Alice". Apologies as I'm really quite new to jq advanced topics. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you for catching that @Inian!

Yes that's actually just a sample snippet of what is a more complex output.

I have been trying foreach and if loops but the json file is actually being generated inside a jenkins pipeline script.

Comment: You should take a look at [Select entries based on multiple values in jq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44704404/5291015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adopting the answer from the linked question in comments with *slight* modification to suit the use-case of OP

```sh
jq -n --argjson names '["Bob", "Alice"]' '
(reduce $names[] as $name ({}; .[$name] = true)) as $set
    | inputs | map(select($set[.Name]))' json
```

The `reduce` function basically creates a hash-map of truth values mapped for each entry of your input names array. Later apply the map on each of the input object. If the condition satisfies, print the object desired.

Or alternatively use the `any/2` function

```sh
jq --argjson names '["Bob", "Alice"]' '
 map(select( .Name as $a | any( $names[]; . == $a) ))' json
```

Comment: I'll test and update this tomorrow thank you

Comment: @pnocti - The solution using $set is likely to be far more efficient in your case; in general, it will be faster unless the time taken to construct $set dominates.

Comment: What if inputs have .Name that is not mentioned in $set?

Comment: @LoganLee Do you mind asking a new question separately for this?