# Filter openapi spec by routes

Tags: jq, openapi

I have an openapi spec on which I'd like to select a subset of paths (thus, filter by key). I'm having trouble getting the with_entries command to work to filter a list of paths.

Sample JSON:

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {},
  "host": "petstore.swagger.io",
  "basePath": "/api",
  "schemes": [],
  "consumes": [],
  "produces": [],
  "paths": {
    "/pets": {},
    "/pets/{id}": {}
  },
  "definitions": {}
}
```

The input is the json, the output should be the same json, but only the '/pets' route left in (filtering the "/pets/{id}" route out).

We will have a list of probably 20 routes, so would like a solution that is clean and allows me to specify the ~20 routes separately as a variable.

I tried some of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704404/select-entries-based-on-multiple-values-in-jq) and came up with this: (We also need to capture and keep other top-level keys, but I'm focused on path filtering for now, but an answer for that would be most welcome!)

```
.paths
["/pets"] as $whitelist
| with_entries( select( .key as $k | any( $whitelist[]; . == $k) ) )
```

However, this gives an error (`jq: error (at file.json:xx): Cannot iterate over null (null)`

So there are two problems to solve:

1. How to keep all of the elements in the original json, but filter out some of the paths
2. How to make the script 'clean' so that the list of paths to keep can be easily maintained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer building a lookup table.

```sh
jq '
   ( ["/pets"] | map({ (.): true }) | add ) as $whitelist |
   .paths |= with_entries(select( $whitelist[.key] ))
'
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/AF5mQB03ns)

Comment: Awesome. Would you mind adding some explanation of what is going on?

Comment: I mean, I did. I build a lookup table (`{ "/pets": true } as $whitelist`), then I select the entries with a key that's in the lookup table (`select( $whitelist[.key] )`)