# jq filter: ok if item not in list

Tags: arrays, json, jq, indexof

(jq newbie here, sorry if this question has an obvious answer :) )

I'd like to filter json based on whether a value is *not* in a list.

Here's a concrete example:

*Input*

```
[ 
    {
        "n": "A",
        "a": 659533330984,
        "vals": {
            "n2": "B",
            "b": 5193941030
        }
     },
    {
        "n": "A",
        "a": 659533330984,
        "vals": {
            "n2": "C",
            "b": 4872891707
        }
    },
    {
        "n": "B",
        "a": 659533330984,
        "vals": {
            "n2": "C",
            "b": 4872891707
        }
    }
]
```

*Filter*

`[.n, .vals.n2]` not in  `(["A", "B"], ["B", "C"])`

Hence, in jq, I tried the following commands (also based on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563115/how-to-use-jq-to-filter-select-items-not-in-list))

```
jq '[ .[] | select([.n, .vals.n2] as $i | (["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]) | index($i) | not )]'
```

and

```
jq '[ .[] | select([.n, .vals.n2] != (["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]))]'
```

However, the both commands give the output

```
[
  {
    "n": "A",
    "a": 659533330984,
    "vals": {
      "n2": "B",
      "b": 5193941030
    }
  },
  {
    "n": "A",
    "a": 659533330984,
    "vals": {
      "n2": "C",
      "b": 4872891707
    }
  },
  {
    "n": "A",
    "a": 659533330984,
    "vals": {
      "n2": "C",
      "b": 4872891707
    }
  },
  {
    "n": "B",
    "a": 659533330984,
    "vals": {
      "n2": "C",
      "b": 4872891707
    }
  }
]
```

whereas this would be the desired output -- without duplicates and with logical AND of all "blacklisted" values:

```
[
  {
    "n": "A",
    "a": 659533330984,
    "vals": {
      "n2": "C",
      "b": 4872891707
    }
  }
]
```

It makes sense that the second command does not work, since if I understood correctly, the comma operator basically means that jq evaluates the expression once for every listed element - hence the duplicates. However simply piping through `unique` does not help since the output should not contain *any* of the filter pairs.

The only other idea I have at the moment is to pipe select through select through select... for each item in the "blacklist". However, I'd like to read the blacklist as an input -- I could dynamically create the command, but I was wondering whether there is a more beautiful solution? It feels like as if there must be...

I'd be very happy to hear your input on how to approach this best.

I'm using jq version jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression:

```
([.n, .vals.n2]) not in (["A", "B"], ["B", "C"])
```

would be equivalent to:

```
([.n, .vals.n2]) != ["A", "B"] and ([.n, .vals.n2]) != ["B", "C"]
```

As you have it here:

```
select([.n, .vals.n2] != (["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]))
```

it's not quite the same as the comma effectively makes it an `or`.

You'll need to do something more like this:

```
select([.n, .vals.n2] as $v | $v != ["A", "B"] and $v != ["B", "C"])
```

or

```
select([.n, .vals.n2] as $v | all(["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]; $v != .))
```

Also if you wanted to stick with your first approach, you would have to put the values in an array and not just separated by a comma.

```
select([.n, .vals.n2] as $i | [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]] | index($i) | not)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful reply! 
FYI, for me, the last command you mentioned returns the input (non-filtered): https://jqplay.org/s/yUztANtOe5
The second-last command works :)

Answer (score 1):

When using `index` to find the index of an array (say $x), you have to write:

```
index([$x])
```

(This has to do with the fact that `index` is designed to work in a uniform way on both JSON strings and arrays.)

### An efficient solution

```
[["A", "B"], ["B", "C"]] as $blacklist
| map( [.n, .vals.n2] as $i
       | select( $blacklist | index([$i]) | not) )
```

#### From the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)

> : Given an array, A, containing an item, X, how can I find the least index of X in A? Why does [[1](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)] | index([1](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)) return null rather than 0? Why does [1,2] | index([1,2]) return 0 rather than null?
>
> A: The simplest uniform method for finding the least index of X in an array is to query for [X] rather than X itself, that is: index([X]).
>
> By contrast, the filter index([1,2]) attempts to find [1,2] as a subsequence of contiguous items in the input array. This is for uniformity with the behavior of t | index(s) where s and t are strings.
>
> If X is not an array, then index([X]) may be abbreviated to index(X).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! 
Maybe I did something wrong, for me this didn't give the expected result: https://jqplay.org/s/_ffcIjiTj3

Comment: The logic there is wrong. Move the iteration outside the `select`.